# Wordpress Subcategory template

Tags: categories, templates, template-hierarchy

First of all on this forum i found a lot of sollutions that got really close. But i wasn't able to solve my issue completely

I structured my website using category-subcategoriy- posts. Every once in a while a category is added or removed.

I managed to create a template for the category, which automaticly loads links the the available subcategories

For the subcategories i want to create a different template.
I managed to do this manually by creating the category-$slug.php
But because new categories & sub categories are created all the time, i would like to do this dynamicly

So whenever i create a new subcategory, the subcategory template is automaticly used. Instead of having to create a new category-slug.php every time.

How can i do this? (i guess this is a noobs question)

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need such thing and what you are trying to do in each template? I don't get the point. How do you know the code that needs to be dinamically generated and inserted in the template? I guess that you need less templates files with a smarter code.

Comment: Okay, the best example is by handing you the website as well
http://www.thebesthousemusic.com.
On the EDM genres page we will be listing all the EDM Genres out there:
(These will be the categories)
Electro house
Bass house
Future House

For each style (category) we will list:
Playlists
mixes
releases
etc.
<these will be the subcategories>

in these subcategories, we will post the latest playlist
So for instance http://www.thebesthousemusic.com/electro-house/playlist/251120162
would be the second playlist posted today

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you don't need a separate template for each (sub)category at all. You need a template that dinamically generates the (sub)categories lists. In short, instead of dinamically generating the code for each template output, you should use a template that dinamically generates the output. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I think were on the same page here, but i have a little trouble explaining myself.
One template for all sub categories would be what im looking for.

Comment: Let's see if I understand your situation. Do you need to get the list of subcategories of current category or something like that?